# Verse about two sons

Tags: money

There is a verse that i remember that talks about a father with two sons.  The father gives money to both of his sons.  One son invests his money and returns it to his father after becoming wealthy, or something like that, and the other son squanders it.  If i remember correctly, even though the second son squandered his money the father still showed him compassion.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about verse identification. This type of question is off-topic by today's site standards: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Luke 15:11-32](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2015:11-32;&version=NIV;)

Its called the [Parable of the Prodigal Son](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Prodigal_Son)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are scrambling two different parables.

The one with two sons, one of which squanders his inheratence but is welcomed back is found in [Luke 15:11-32](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke+15:11-31/)

The one about a master who lends money to his servants, and some of them give him a return on his investment but one does not is found in [Luke 19:11-27](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke+19:11-27/).